# convert SOAP request to iOS soap message

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, request

I have been working with SOAP request and tested with `SOAPUI` and it was working very good. But when include in `SOAPMEASSAGE` in iOS and test it, I get error in the response and can't parse the data

The working request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:prod="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProdigyDAL.Model.Search">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetLatestNews>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:websiteID>1</tem:websiteID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:languageID>2</tem:languageID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:categoryID>105</tem:categoryID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:currentNewsUniqueName>0</tem:currentNewsUniqueName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:pageInfo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prod:PageNumber>0</prod:PageNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prod:PageSize>3</prod:PageSize>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prod:TotalRowCount>0</prod:TotalRowCount>
         </tem:pageInfo>
      </tem:GetLatestNews>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

my soapmessage

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>""<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\" xmlns:prod=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProdigyDAL.Model.Search/\">"
                         "<soapenv:Header/>"
                         "<soapenv:Body>"
                         "<GetLatestNews>"
                         "<websiteID>1</websiteID>"
                         "<languageID>2</languageID>"
                         "<categoryID>105</categoryID>"
                         "<currentNewsUniqueName>0<currentNewsUniqueName>"
                         "<pageInfo><a:PageNumber>0</a:PageNumber><a:PageSize>3</a:PageSize><a:TotalRowCount>0</a:TotalRowCount></pageInfo>"
                         "</GetLatestNews>"
                         "</soapenv:Body>"
                         "</soapenv:Envelope>"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demoserver.tacme.net:3030/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx.svc"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"demoserver.tacme.net:3030" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

can you advise, what is wrong in my message?

Comment: What's HTTP header of your message? Usually you need to put SOAP action name in http header

Comment: Might this helps https://github.com/ilnar-aliullov/HSFramework

Comment: the SOAP request updated with URL and SOAPACTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of issues in your soapMessage

```
1. <soapenv:Envelope ..> but closing tag is </soap:Envelope>
2. There is no tag <xmlns:prod... these are parameters of <soapenv:Envelope..
3. etc... (another mismatches)
```

BOTTOM LINE: Make exactly the same as your working request

```
//Put somewhere in your code 
NSLog("%@",soapMessage);
```

The copy and paste in a file e.g. request.xml
Then in terminal

```
xmllint --format request.xml
```

And see if it is a valid XML document

Comment: Thanks IInar, I fixed the message and edited my question. it is connected and receive data but some fault in XML can't parse the data. can you help

Comment: Dears, I fixed the message issue, but I have a very strange issue with the array. After using XML Parser, and parse the data in mutable string, and add sting to array when using in Tableview, all stings appear in one raw and repeated in all raws. for example if I have 2 strings from the server xxx & yyy when parse it, i found the string in array like xxx yyyy and repeated in 2 raws. what do you think?

Comment: Obviously you have a bug in your XML parser. Refer to this apple doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html Here you'll find a nice guide and examples. (I based my parser on it)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i solved it now. But I have another question if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118906/soap-message-for-tableview-with-sections-in-objective-c